# Slow video reproduction quality in youtube with chromium and firefox in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: firefox, flash, chromium, youtube

That's it I can't watch a video in Youtube simple because the reproduction is too slow and it's somewhat paused. I seem to have Flash player plugin installed in both chromium and firefox (I haven't tried chrome though, I'll try it later to see what happens) I don't know if that's enough but I just need to fix that bug. Could someone advice me to do something? Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has flash built-in.  You will have to uninstall flash since Chrome may have issues with trying to deal with two versions of Flash.

I currently use Chrome and find the built-in flash good.

Chromium, the open source version of Chrome, does not have built-in flash.  Therefore, you will have to download Chrome directly from Google.

The other option is to create a RAMDisk.  RAMDisk can speed up flash videos.  Furthermore, 64-bit Ubuntu seems to be faster than 32-bit Ubuntu.  Although, the computer must be able to support 64-bit.

Adobe stopped providing updates for Flash.  Therefore, Chrome is the only way to keep up-to-date with the latest flash versions in Linux.

As for me, I have used Firefox, Chromium, and Chrome.  Chrome works the best.  Unfortunately, I had to uninstall PulseAudio and install ALSA.  PulseAudio was causing some issues with some flash games.  The volume control kept going on then mute which caused some issues.

From what I understand, Flash works best with ALSA.  In any case, trial and error maybe the only way to find out what works best in your system.

Hope this helps.